# Can anyone refer me to a good study material to study Petrov Classification from?

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, metric-tensor, resource-recommendations, curvature

I am currently trying to study [Petrov Classification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Petrov_classification) so I may start my research in the summer. I have completed a year of GR course at the level of Sean Carroll.

Comment: I would suggest first to study spinor approach in GR. With it Petrov classification is extremely simple and elegant.

Comment: Can you refer me to a resource dealing with discussion of Spinors approach?

Comment: There is a book by P. O'Donnell “Introduction to 2-spinors in GR”. There is also a classic  2-volume monograph by Penrose & Rindler, though this might be harder.

Answer (score 4):

I recommend you to first have a good handle of Spinors in GR. I personally took this route in getting a grip on Spinors:

1. A Child's Guide to Spinors : http://www.weylmann.com/spinor.pdf
2. An Introduction to Spinors : https://arxiv.org/abs/1312.3824
3. Penrose, Roger (1960). "A spinor approach to general relativity"

The third one is going to be a smooth if you have gone through the first two documents which introduces to spinors in a wonderful way.

Then you can directly jump into these for further learning about Petrov Classification:

1. Petrov, A.Z. (2000). "Classification of spaces defined by gravitational fields". General Relativity and Gravitation. 32 (8): 1665–1685 (This is an English translation)
2. Hall, Graham (2004). Symmetries and Curvature Structure in General Relativity (World Scientific Lecture Notes in Physics)